# Send cookies between subdomains

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cookies

I have an ajax request from one subdomain to another i.e. sub1.example.com => sub2.example.com, while I have a cookie for all domain. (cookie `domain='.example.com'`)

```
document.cookie='myCookie=value;domain=.exmaple.com'
$.ajax( {url:'sub2.example.com' });
```

But the cookie is not sent to server (node.js server) no matter what.

Why can it be, what can be done about it?

Comment: Did you try sending the domain explicitly for the other subdomain ?

Comment: On visiting `AAA.example.com` set cookie for domain `BBB.example.com`. Please post the `Set-Cookie` and probably `Cookie` header.

Comment: Yeah, have tried, didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem add `withCredentials:true` to the request:

```
$.ajax( {url:'sub2.example.com',
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
     }
    });
```

And in the server side (node.js in my case), add allow `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true`

```
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
```

Domain cookies will be sent.

Comment: I am amazed that even for same domain/site but different origin, this is needed. 
Anyways thanks